# About PREEMPT_RT caveats & local_lock

Tags: linux, locking, preempt-rt

Recently, I am reading about linux locking,from https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/locking/locktypes.html#local-lock
when I read this :

local_lock on RT
The mapping of local_lock to spinlock_t on PREEMPT_RT kernels has a few implications. For example, on a non-PREEMPT_RT kernel the following code sequence works as expected:

```
local_lock_irq(&local_lock);
raw_spin_lock(&lock);
```

and is fully equivalent to:

```
raw_spin_lock_irq(&lock);
```

On a PREEMPT_RT kernel this code sequence breaks because local_lock_irq() is mapped to a per-CPU spinlock_t which neither disables interrupts nor preemption. The following code sequence works perfectly correct on both PREEMPT_RT and non-PREEMPT_RT kernels:

```
local_lock_irq(&local_lock);
spin_lock(&lock);
```

I'm confused by this description, as I know,

- local_lock_irq on PREEMPT_RT is implemented by migrate_disable and a percpu spinlock, it means , neither disables interrupts nor preemption
- spin_lock  on PREEMPT_RT is implemented  by RT_MUTEX
- IRQ is implemented by interrupt thread

so,on the first sample, on PREEMPT_RT  kernel, since after local_lock_irq it may be preempted by another thread(interrupt thread)， so here said *"this code sequence breaks"* right?

```
local_lock_irq(&local_lock);
raw_spin_lock(&lock);
```

but on the second sample,we know on a  NON-PREEMPT_RT kernel, since spin_lock equals raw_spin_lock, I think it's  code sequence equals the first sample, But on a PREEMPT_RT, after local_lock_irq,it still can be preempted by another thread(interrupt thread), why does it says  "code sequence works perfectly correct on both PREEMPT_RT and non-PREEMPT_RT kernels" ??????

```
local_lock_irq(&local_lock);
spin_lock(&lock);
```

spin_lock is just a kind of  SMP concurrency protection mechanism, whatever I use raw_spin_lock or spin_lock, on a PREEMPT_RT, It just affects whether I can be preempted